Discord bot commands not working in Discord Server
I'm trying to create a Discord bot, which would automatically give a role to users. My prefix is fetched through JSON (Config.json), and I'm using the discord.js library.
index.js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db");
const config = require("./config.json");

const client = new Client({ intents: 32767, });

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot is online!");
});

client.execute = async function (client, message, args, prefix) {
  const commands = require(`./commands/autorole`);
  commands.execute(client, message, args, prefix);
};

client.login(config.token);

autorole.js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db");

module.exports = {
  name: "autorole",
  aliases: ["ar"],
  description: "Add or remove auto role.",
  execute(client, message, args, prefix) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
      // Check if the member has permission
      const noPermEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#ff0000")
        .setTitle("❌ Insufficient Permissions ❌")
        .setDescription("You don't have permission to use this command.")
        .setTimestamp();
      return message.channel.send(noPermEmbed);
    }

    const action = args[0];
    const role =
      message.mentions.roles.first() ||
      message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === args[1]);

    if (!action || !role) {
      const invalidUsageEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#ff0000")
        .setTitle("❌ Invalid Usage ❌")
        .setDescription(`Please use \`${prefix}autorole add/remove @role\`.`)
        .setTimestamp();
      return message.channel.send(invalidUsageEmbed);
    }

    const botRolePosition = message.guild.me.roles.highest.position;
    if (role.position >= botRolePosition) {
      const cantAddEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#ff0000")
        .setTitle("❌ Cannot Add Role ❌")
        .setDescription(
          "The role you are trying to add is equal or above my highest role position.",
        )
        .setTimestamp();
      return message.channel.send(cantAddEmbed);
    }

    if (action === "add" || action === "a") {
      db.set(`autorole_${message.guildId}`, role.id);
      if (
        role.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS") ||
        role.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS") ||
        role.permissions.has("MANAGE_GUILD") ||
        role.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES") ||
        role.permissions.has("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS") ||
        role.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")
      ) {
        const dangerEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor("#ff0000")
          .setTitle("⚠️ Warning: Dangerous Role Added ⚠️")
          .setDescription(
            `The role you added has dangerous permissions!\n\nRole: ${role}`,
          )
          .setTimestamp();
        return message.channel.send(dangerEmbed);
      } else {
        const successEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor("#00ff00")
          .setTitle("✅ Auto Role Added ✅")
          .setDescription(`Auto role \`${role.name}\` added successfully.`)
          .setTimestamp();
        return message.channel.send(successEmbed);
      }
    } else if (action === "remove" || action === "rm") {
      db.delete(`autorole_${message.guildId}`);
      const removedEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#00ff00")
        .setTitle("✅ Auto Role Removed ✅")
        .setDescription("Auto role removed successfully.")
        .setTimestamp();
      return message.channel.send(removedEmbed);
    } else {
      const invalidActionEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#ff0000")
        .setTitle("❌ Invalid Action ❌")
        .setDescription(`Please use \`${prefix}autorole add/remove @role\`.`)
        .setTimestamp();
      return message.channel.send(invalidActionEmbed);
    }
  },
};

config.json-
{
  "token":"-",
  "prefix":"."
}


Issue: Bot commands not working on server

I'm trying to run the application, but when I try to run commands in the Discord server nothing happens. No errors in the console.

I'm not sure db.set(autorole_${message.guildId}, role.id); is right, try db.set(autorole_${message.guild.id}, role.id); -- nothing else seems to stand out.

kk i will see that but even autorole seems not working any possible fix?

Currently the standard for JS-written discord bots, is to have a slashcommandbuilder. Custom prefixes are a thing of the past due to message intent . Also, you need to register your commands through the API. How to register commands

Maybe it's how you're overriding the execute method.
Try replacing the execute with this:
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'autorole') {
    const autoroleCommand = require('./commands/autorole');
    autoroleCommand.execute(client, message, args, config.prefix);
  }
});


This way, your code will fire when commands are executed (dependant on input) rather than calling your code directly.
Hope this helps

Still nothing. I tried running nothing happened still .

When I try replicate your code, I get an error: Used disallowed intents -- I also couldn't find a combination for 32767 - the closest I could find was 32768 (MESSAGE_INTENTS)

When you run node index.js -- do you not get an error?

OK, I've been trying to get a bot up and running for the last two hours and hit a wall where, no matter how simple my request, I couldn't make it work. It is up the the intent and permissions. I set up my client with const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] }); -- go to your applications and click the bot you're testing, click "Bot" on the left side and ensure all three checkboxes under "Privileged Gateway Intents" are checked. This worked for me

32767 is for all intents as far i know
na when i run node index.js i dont got any error
wait i will change intents and check and i have checked all 3 dont wry i will update you
